# Getting parameter from forward

Tags: java, jsp, parameters, forward

I'm working on a project and I have a problem. I send a parameter from a jsp page via forward to another jsp page and although it has the value that I declared (I printed it and it works), when I use it in an if clause the code doesn't work. Here is the part of the code:

```
String parameter = request.getParameter("loginparam");  //loginparam is the the name of parameter in the forward statement whick has value "now"

    if(parameter == "now"){
         prints the jsp page

    }else{

         response.sendRedirect("mainpage.jsp");
    }
```

It always redirects me in mainpage although when I print parameter it has the "now" value.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/03/how-to-compare-two-string-in-java.html

Answer (score 1):

Try with,

```
if(parameter.equals("now")){
```

And [Read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)